# zoom an imageView and also be able to launch another activity by clicking on it android

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap, click, zooming

This is my first question so please forgive me if there are mistakes.

I already have a bitmap with the image and when I click in the `ImageView` the application launches another activity.

I don't know how to zoom (and pan) an `ImageView`, and if I click it, launch a new activity.

### Could you help me please?

update i tried with this library but i don't know where is the error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iEXI.png)
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bl6a.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an open source library, [ZoomLayout](https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout), it has built in support of ZoomImageView that supports 2D pan and zoom. If you don't want to use an external library you'll need to write a custom view yourself to intercept gestures and use a Canvas to scale/crop the bitmap.

Comment: i don't care to use an external library, the problem is that i don't know how to use this librery ^^" if you could write an example i will be very greatful

Comment: Hi you can just replace your ImageView in layout with ZoomImageView, adding some more links to help you test the library [Installation](https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/about/install) , [Usage](https://natario1.github.io/ZoomLayout/docs/zoom-image), Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: i'll try this night, thank you so much, im not sure how to launch a new activity with this library, just using onClick() ??

Comment: Yes onClick() would work just like a normal ImageView.

Comment: Hi, i tried but there were some mistakes, i edited the post to add some picture of the error, i don't know if you know where is the mistake?

Comment: Did you sync the project after adding jcenter() to the root build.gradle file?

Comment: yes and nothing, could it be because i'm using googlemaps library too?  do you know an alternative?